# Pulling Data from other Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to pull data from a webpage and display it on my webpage. An iframe will not work. An example of the type of data I would like too pull is the table on this website: http://www2.usfirst.org/2012comp/events/SC/ScheduleQual.html Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use [jquery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

But first, use a server side script that will load the page from (a "buffer" or a "proxy") because crossdomain javascript is usually forbidden.